# Trouble using Spring Data repository with Generics

Tags: java, spring, generics

Getting compilation error as below

```
*Inferred type 'my.domain.model.CustomerDemographicsBasicDetails' for type parameter S is not within its bounds; should extend capture <? extends my.domain.model.CustomerDemographicsBasicDetails>*
```

for **`customerBasicDetailsRepository(details.getClass()).save(details);`**

For the following Generic Repository contract

```
package my.domain.model;

import java.util.List;

public interface CustomerBasicDetailsRepository<T extends CustomerDemographicBasicDetails> {

    List<T> findAll(Iterable<String> customerIds);

    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    T findOne(String customerId);

    boolean exists(String customerId);

    void delete(T entity);
}
```

and the corresponding JpaRepository implementation

```
package my.infrastructure.persistence.jpa;

import my.domain.model.CustomerBasicDetailsRepository;
import my.domain.model.CustomerDemographicBasicDetails;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface JpaCustomerBasicDetailsRepository<T extends CustomerDemographicBasicDetails>
        extends JpaRepository<T, String>,
        CustomerBasicDetailsRepository<T> {

    @Override
    List<T> findAll(Iterable<String> customerIds);

    @Override
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    @Override
    T findOne(String customerId);

    @Override
    boolean exists(String customerId);

    @Override
    void delete(T entity);
}
```

and the domain model types below

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_TYPE")
@Table(name = "******")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomerDemographicBasicDetails {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BUS")
@Table(name = "********")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class BusinessCustomer extends CustomerDemographicBasicDetails {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("IND")
@Table(name="******")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class IndividualCustomer extends CustomerDemographicBasicDetails {
}
```

and repository lookup thro factory method below

```
public static <T extends CustomerDemographicBasicDetails> CustomerBasicDetailsRepository<T> customerBasicDetailsRepository(Class<T> type) {
    return (CustomerBasicDetailsRepository<T>) applicationContext.getBean(CustomerBasicDetailsRepository.class);
}
```

Comment: "S extends T" S save(S entity);

method like these is also defined in JpaRepository

try: extends JpaRepository "T extends CustomerDemographicBasicDetails, String"

Comment: The method is from JpaRepository but for the purpose of abstraction. defined an interface at the domain layer as CustomerBasicDetailsRepository which exposes methods of the infrastructure layer into the domain layer

Comment: also, to do it correctly, you should have extended jpa repository with your interface CustomerBasicDetailsRepository, but add to it @norepositorybean. More info here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning

Comment: applicationContext.getBean(CustomerBasicDetailsRepository.class);

in this line you try to get bean of CustomerBasicDetailsRepository, but did you properly define that bean, or did you expect Spring to create one with proper generic for you?